# Join two entities in a non entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, sqlresultsetmapping

I want to join two entities in a non-entity class, which will have the two entities as attributes of the class.

Take this as example:

```
@Entity
public class A {
}

@Entity
public class B {
}

public class C {
    private A a;
    private B b;
}
```

I found a solution using SqlResultSetMapping but I don't want to manually specify each column of A and B, because there would be 20+ columns.

The other solution that I found, was to use a JPQL query that will return an Object array results [ ], where results[0] is A and results[1] is B.

My ideea was a combination of both and I see it like this:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(targetClass=C.class, 
entities={
@EntityResult (targetClass=A.class)
@EntityResult (targetClass=B.class)
}
```

Given that both A and B have multiple columns, which is the best way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using JPQL (and it also should work in hibernate) you can take advantage of the resultset class strategy.

**1)** Add constructor to your C class:

```
public C(A aEntity, B bEntity){
  this.a = aEntity;
  this.b = bEntity;
}
```

**2)** Create normal query and use NEW operator with fully qualified `C` class name which would take A and B as its constructor arguments:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select new com.mypkg.C(a as aEntity, b as bEntity) 
                                   from A a, B b where a.id = b.a_id");
List<C> cList = (List<C>)query.list();
```

Comment: I get: `line 1:156: unexpected token: a`

Comment: Still the same problem. Are you sure this is a valid example?